# I have a 11+year old 15ft tree in AZ that has only one live, leafy, seeding, healthy branch, all others are dead, can I save it?

Tags: trees

I have a 15foot tree in front that has one living, healthy branch loaded with leaves with about 12+ totally dead, dried out branches? There are a few small branches sprouting from the living branch base and where all branches junction at trunk, nowhere else? How can I save it? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi Ben, we can give you a better answer with some photos, thanks

Comment: Any evidence of mould or fungal activity in the trunk anywhere? either that or soft, seeping areas anywhere? what kind of tree is it?

Comment: No fungal or seeping areas anywhere? It originally had a layer of bark that turned black and fell off to expose a clean, clear smooth bark w/ marking or discoloration? Not sure what kind of tree it is though, sorry? Not all that great with pictures but will try in next couple days, Thanks, Ben!